# How to have a (user-interactable) default string for getLine?

Tags: haskell

I want to present a terminal user an editable string, in place of giving an empty buffer to write.

I'm thinking something like a text form with a default string, much common in UI.

Is there any trick using System.IO to simulate this kind of behavior, since more complex libraries (like ansi-terminal) doesn't provide this utility?

Comment: System.Console.Haskeline

Comment: Thanks! That had exactly what I needed and more!

Answer (score 1):

As recomended by n.m. , `getInputLineWithInitial` from `System.Console.Haskeline`did the trick!